# French equivalent of "I just wanted to say a quick thank you for ..."

Tags: expressions

I wonder if there is a French equivalent of this English expression. I mean, without using the usual suspects: « merci d’avoir fait ... » or « je te suis reconnaissant d’avoir fait ... ». Something suitably casual, something you say in passing, when you don't want to make a big deal out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the “**quick**” part, I’d rely on the notion of “small,” to which you could add either “vite fait” or “en passant,” (or neither, and maybe even both):

> [“Un petit merci vite
>   fait”](http://forum.lws-hosting.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=382). (from
>   *LWS.fr*)
>
> [“Un petit merci, en
>   passant”](http://blogues.lapresse.ca/lagace/2009/08/17/un-petit-merci-en-passant/)
>   (from *blogues.lapresse.ca*)

As to how to present/preface the sentiment, you could use:

> [“**Juste** un petit merci
>   … pour”](http://www.jeuxvideo.fr/forum/communaute/juste-un-petit-merci-en-passant-id103918-page1.html)
>   (from *jeuxvideo.fr*);
>
> [“**Voilà** un petit merci
>   … pour”](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-24300-74261-1-0-1-0-un-petit-merci-a-la-communaute.htm)
>   (from *jeuxvideo.com* [down in the comment]);
>   or (unless you find it
>   too close to the usual suspects)
>
> [“**Je voulais juste te dire** un petit merci
>   … pour”](http://www.cuk.ch/articles/2787) (from *cuk.ch*)

Answer (score 2):

Je ne trouve rien de plus. Je peux très bien imaginer un dialogue qui contiendrait:

> Ah! Au fait... merci de m'avoir dépanné ce matin, j'étais vraiment coincé.